# GAS: how can I make this script faster?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-apps-script, time

The sheet has multiple rows joined by ";" and I need to expand the strings and also keep the table IDs.

| ID | Column X: Joined Rows |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | a;bcdfh;345;xyw... |
| 02 | aqwx;tyuio;345;xyw... |
| 03 | wxcv;gth;2364;x89... |

```
function expand_joins(range) {
  var output2 = [];
  for(var i = 0, iLen = range.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    var s = range[i][1].split(";");    
    for(var j = 0, jLen = s.length; j < jLen; j++) {
      var output1 = []; 
      for(var k = 0, kLen = range[0].length; k < kLen; k++) {
        if(k == 1) {
          output1.push(s[j]);
        } else {
          output1.push(range[i][k]);
        }
      }
      output2.push(output1);
    }    
  }
  return output2;
}
```

**Desirable Output**: *two columns*

| ID | Output |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | a |
| 01 | bcdfh |
| 01 | 345 |
| 01 | xyw |
| 01 | ... |
| 02 | aqwx |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

If you're using the V8 runtime (new IDE) you can try the following:

```js
function expandJoins(range) {
    return range
        .map(row => row[1]
            .split(';')
            .map(splitItem => [row[0], splitItem])
        )
        .flat();
}
```

Comment: It is good, but the output is not what is expected. Let me update the question with a desirable output.

Comment: I updated the question with a desirable output, which aligns with the example code from the question.

Comment: @Joan What is this data structure that you are reading from? Is it an array, or a list or  a table? Also TheAddonDepot updated the answer. Can you please check if it answers your question?

Comment: Yes, it is perfect and your script is much faster! Also, @stackoverflow this is not an opinion-based question, it is about script performance.